# how i set lookupedit display format

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Tables dt like this:

```
index StartDate         EndDate
1   2015/03/23 22:00    2015/03/23 23:00
2   2015/03/23 22:00    2015/03/23 22:00
3   2015/03/23 22:00    2015/03/23 22:00
```

I have set:

```
lookupedit1.Properties.ValueMember = "StartDate";
lookupedit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "StartDate";
```

So, the value has show OK, long date `Type`, but i want the `DisplayMemeber` like short date type.
I have try any of below, but it's havn't work expectly.

```
lookupedit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "yyyy-MM-dd";
lookupedit1.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd";
lookupedit1.Properties.EditFormat.FormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

How can i resolve my questions?

Answer (score 2):

> i want the DisplayMemeber like short date type

You can use the standard `d` display-format string for short date (culture specific, described in the [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) document in MSDN.). To specify [formatting-behavior](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2141) you should add the specific column into the LookUp edit:

```
lookUpEdit1.Properties.Columns.Add(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo()
        {
            FieldName = "StartDate",
            FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime,
            FormatString = "d" // short date
        });
lookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource = new List<Order> { 
    new Order(){ StartDate = new DateTime(2015, 03, 23, 23, 0, 0) },
    new Order(){ StartDate = new DateTime(2015, 03, 24, 23, 0, 0) },
    new Order(){ StartDate = new DateTime(2015, 03, 25, 23, 0, 0) },
};
```

To setup display-behavior while editing you can use the editor's [Mask](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1497) :

```
lookUpEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "d"; // short date
lookUpEdit1.Properties.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.DateTime;
lookUpEdit1.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true;
```

Comment: yeah , i have validate your answer. and it's work OK.
     
     `Mask.EditMask = ... ;`
     `Mask.MaskType = ...;`
     `Mask.UseMaskAsDisPisplayFormat = ...;`
     

thank you.